# PHP RegEx Remove words from string which contain non-letters/numbers

Tags: php, regex

Could anyone please help me with this regular expression, as I'm not sure how to implement it.

I need a regex for removing all words from a string which contain at least one character which is not a UTF-8 letter or number, or punctuation in the middle of the word (but not at the end).

Examples:

```
This is Â®Aix string
A bad str?ng is here
```

The first example contains `®`, which is not a letter, number or punctuation.
The second example contains punctuation in the middle.

I need to remove these bad words, but keep the rest of the string intact. E.g. `This is string`, `A bad is here`.

Please note that `A bad string? is here` would not contain any bad words, as the punctuation is at the end of the word.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have other languages except of english? because `UTF-8 letter or number` needs http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php which might be not supported everywhere.

Comment: Accented characters can be included, anything from the Latin alphabet including accents. But Eastern, Russian, Greek, etc. characters can be excluded.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '/\b            # Start of word
    [\p{L}\p{N}]+   # One or more Unicode letters
    [^\s\p{L}\p{N}] # One non-letter (and non-whitespace), followed by
    [^\s\p{P}]+     # at least one non-whitespace, non-punctuation character
    \b              # End of word
    \s*             # optional following whitespace
    /xu', 
    '', $subject);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will not match if the word begins with a non-letter character. Also this will consider numbers as bad, when they should be OK.

Comment: @Alasdair: I had overlooked the numbers part - fixed it now. You wrote "contains a ... character *in the middle of the word*" which excludes the first letter in my interpretation. So what exactly are the rules?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I’m thinking that PHP doesn’t need braces for the 7 single-letter general-category properies.   I think it’s C♯ where you need those. I much prefer systems where `\pL` is only half-again longer than `\w`, not those with `\p{L}`, which is 2.5x the size and gets messy to look at. But I know some who think the braces helps them read it better.